# Retaining scope value from the cookie store on page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have the following code in one of my controllers.

```
$scope.artistId = $cookies.artistId; 

$scope.artistName = $cookies.artistName;

$scope.switchArtist = function(artist) {

    $scope.artistName = '';
    $scope.artistId = '';

    $scope.artist = artist;

    $cookies.artistName = artist.name;
    $cookies.artistId = artist.id;

    $scope.artistName = artist.name;
    $scope.artistId = artist.id;

    $rootScope.$broadcast(ARTIST_EVENTS.switchedArtist);

};
```

Then in my view I have

```
{{ artistName }}
```

When I trigger the $scope.switchArtist(); function, that works. However when I refresh the page $scope.artistName loses it's value in my view again.

**[edit]**

I'm using angularjs 1.3.14

Comment: What version of Angular are you using? I believe it makes a difference related to $cookies.

Comment: Apologies,  I should have included that, I'm using 1.3.14 @ArthurFrankel

Comment: Hmmm.. then the dot notation is okay.  I would check the following: 1) try in another browser;  2) Create another function that you can call from a button click and see if the value $cookies.artistId is there before you refresh the page; 3) use chrome tools and check your cookies.  Let me know if you don't know how to do the last one.

Comment: @ArthurFrankel thanks for your help! The cookie is being set when I check in Chrome tools. I created this function to test

$scope.setStuff = function() {
    console.log($cookies.artistName);
    $scope.artistName = 'Hello';
 };

The name appears in the console, but 'Hello' doesn't in the view

Comment: I created a plunker (similar) that works fine.  I'm assuming you have ng-cookies specified in your module and $cookies in your controller via DI.  http://plnkr.co/edit/IdFhlucyOpa1ZF49zsx3

Comment: @ArthurFrankel It turns out I had an ng-if further up the dom that wasn't being met! Many apologies, and thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use .get and .put for $cookies instead of regular dot notation.  You can see here in the [1.4 version docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) - assuming that's what you are using.